# Mean of a 4D array across selected dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, statistics, mean

I am using the `mean` function in MATLAB on a 4D matrix.

The matrix is a `32x2x20x7` array and I wish to find the mean of each row, of all columns and elements of 3rd dimension, for each 4th dimension.

So basically **mean(data(b,:,:,c))** [pseudo-code] for each `b, c`.

However, when I do this it spits me out separate means for each 3rd dimension, do you know how I can get it to give me one mean for the above equation - **so it would be** (**32x7**=)224 means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with two calls to `mean`, there will be small numerical differences in the result depending on the order of operations. As such, I suggest doing this with one call to `mean` to avoid such concerns:

```
squeeze(mean(reshape(data,size(data,1),[],size(data,4)),2))
```

Or if you dislike `squeeze` (some people do!):

```
mean(permute(reshape(data,size(data,1),[],size(data,4)),[1 3 2]),3)
```

Both commands use `reshape` to combine the second and third dimensions of `data`, so that a single call to `mean` on the new larger second dimension will perform all of the required computations.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it without loops:

```
data = rand(32,2,20,7); %// example data
squeeze(mean(mean(data,3),2))
```

The key is to use a second argument to [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mean.html), which specifies across which dimension the mean is taken (in your case: dimensions 2 and 3). [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) just removes singleton dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
a=rand(32,2,20,7);

for i=1:32
    for j=1:7
        c=a(i,:,:,j);
        mean(c(:))
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry can you annotate this, I am a little confused.

Comment: Ooo sorry new to this. :)